# How can some letter hide in SQL Server?

Tags: sql-server, command, masking

I want to some column masking in sql column.

How can I do sql command?

Comment: What version of SQL Server are you using?

Comment: I use SQL Server 2014.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you are using SQL Server 2008 or later, we can try using `REPLICATE` with `SUBSTRING`:

```
SELECT
    '**' + SUBSTRING(col, 3, 2) + REPLICATE('*', LEN(col) - 4) AS mask
FROM yourTable;
```

[image]

### Demo

A nicer way to handle this would be to make use of regular expressions, but SQL Server does not really support a regex replace.  So I offer this as an alternative.